# Bootstrap dropdown menu pops up under navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I have a page with a form where there is a multi-select dropdown menu with a lot of option. When clicked on the menu pops out but doesnt show all options because a part of it is hidden under the navbar. 
Here is an image of the issue:
[image: https://gyazo.com/62661917913c479a60dd48b21cf798ed]

And this is what the form looks like when the dropdown is not yet clicked:
[image: https://gyazo.com/511e7062e949f850fb31245b2b8628b9]

Here is the code for my dropdown-menu:

```
<div class="form-group">
                <label>Linked Platforms</label>
                <select name="platforms[]" class="selectpicker form-control" multiple title="Platforms">
                    <% platforms.forEach(function(platform){ %>
                    <option value="<%= platform._id %>"><%= platform.name %></option>
                    <% }) %>
                </select>
</div>
```

How do i make the pop up smaller?

Comment: What prevents the lower block with class "form-groups" below?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand the question. There is no lower block except for the button

Comment: In select tag specify the number of display option elements
<select size="20">

Comment: setting size to 20 did not change anything  @Alex

Comment: I have tried putting the form all the way at the bottom of the page but it still pops open the menu all the way to the top and under the navbar